# Is is possible to get ppg(Photoplethysmogram) raw data from a smart watch(moto360) via android?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to get ppg(Photoplethysmogram) raw data from a smart watch(moto360) via android?

Comment: Yes. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444302/android-wear-how-to-get-raw-ppg-data/52337056#52337056